# Array remapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

We have an array of objects

```
var items = [
    { id: 1, order_assigned: 2},
    { id: 2, order_assigned: 4},
    { id: 3, order_assigned: 1},
    { id: 4, order_assigned: 5},
    { id: 5, order_assigned: 3}
];
```

Each have id and some order number.
For example, user changes order number at id 2 to 0. Array now will look like this:

```
var items = [
        { id: 1, order_assigned: 2},
        { id: 2, order_assigned: 0},
        { id: 3, order_assigned: 1},
        { id: 4, order_assigned: 5},
        { id: 5, order_assigned: 3}
    ];
```

Now we need to reindex order_assigned in order to fill gaps in order_assigned order.
i.e. array should look like this

```
var items = [
        { id: 1, order_assigned: 2},
        { id: 2, order_assigned: 0},
        { id: 3, order_assigned: 1},
        { id: 4, order_assigned: 4},
        { id: 5, order_assigned: 3}
    ];
```

Item with id 4 changes order assigned number from 5 to 4, cos there is no item with 4 order assigned number.

Numbering in order_assigned should go in order from 1 to the last established rank. 1, 2, 3, 4. If someone enters 1,2,5,7 to order_assigned it must be converted to 1,2,3,4.
In other words, if there is a gap in order number, all digits after it must be recalculated. No resorting of items order itself needed.

Totally stucked how to do this right way. Please, help!

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but what logic are you using to determine the new `order_assigned`?

Comment: What do you mean by "gaps in order_assigned order"? How is the desired output even sorted (it's still ascending by id)?

Comment: do you have a rule for renumbering?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Numbering should go in order from 1 to the last established rank. 1, 2, 3, 4. If someone enters 1,2,5,7 it must be converted to 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Zhlobopotam I can't see it. How is your second example reflecting that? What must be converted? order_assigned?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to change order_assigned

Comment: I think @TobyMellor's (and mine) confusion is that in your second example, you say "the array should look like this", but the array you show is clearly out of order lol.

Comment: @Amleonard haha

Comment: Your original array has no gaps, it has all the numbers from `0` to `4`. Your desired result has a duplicate `1` in the result. How is this an example of what you want?

Comment: Hmm. Forgot one important thing. Items with zero order_assigned must keep its value. And no need for changing order of items itself. They should be in same order. Only order_assigned changes.

Comment: @Zhlobopotam You need to edit your question and correct the second example

Comment: Reformulated the question. Thank  you for assistance

Comment: @Zhlobopotam Does it matter what order the objects are placed in the array, even if they're all correct?

Comment: Yes. Order of items must remain the same. I need to change only an attribute order_assigned.

Comment: @Zhlobopotam Please check my updated answer and mark if correct. The answer makes the assumption that the IDs are in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking us to order this based on `order_assigned`, then close the gaps between the `order_assigned`.

I'm first sorting the array, then looping through it. I'm then replacing the `order_assigned` value with the current index.

```js
var items = [
    { id: 1, order_assigned: 2},
    { id: 2, order_assigned: 0},
    { id: 3, order_assigned: 1},
    { id: 4, order_assigned: 5},
    { id: 5, order_assigned: 3}
];

items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order_assigned - b.order_assigned;
});

var counter = 0;

for (var index in items) {
    if (items[index].order_assigned === 0) {
        continue;
    } // leave orders that are 0 the same

    items[index].order_assigned = ++counter;
}

items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
}); // sort again on the ID field

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Thank you, Toby! It's exactly that I need!

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortCloseGap(array) {
   return array.slice() // copy
     .sort(function(a, b) { return a.order_assigned - b.order_assigned }) // sort
     .map(function(item, index) { // assign new order
         item.order_assigned = index + 1;
         return item;
     });
}
```

I hope you don't mind the mutability.